# Why google plus seems using ajax to load page content but the url changes?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Typically, when one page is being loaded(when url changes), the first request is the document, but I didn't see document request when click link in gplus, and the url in the address bar sure changed!As you see in the picture bellow.

The first several requests are for scripts and others are all images.I'm quite confused, if they are using scripts to load contents why the url is changing? And if they change the location why is there no request for the page and the animations seem so smooth when redirects to another page.

[image]

Comment: Does the entire URL change or just the #hash section?  You can change the URL hash in script.

Comment: the url might change but it does not mean the script is different. its a good way to stop caching. Also the redirect can be smooth because they could use ajax to load the next page while you are still looking at the same page, and then animate it smoothly when you decide to go firther. look at jquery mobile for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they are using [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) ;) It allows you to add some URLs (for the same domain, of course) in the history, *via* JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

First, you just missed (I don't know how) the requests, because they are there ;)
Just use chrome dev tools for instance, and you'll see them.

Using HTML 5, you can manipulate the browser history and actually change the URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history